# coldfusion cfsavecontent html page with dynamic variables

Tags: coldfusion

As a simple example of the problem:

```
<cfsavecontent variable = "pageOutput">
   <cfoutput>
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
         <title>#page_title#</title>
      </head>
      <body>
         <cfdump var="#URL#">
      </body>
      </html>
   </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
```

I save this page to disk. Then when I call this newly-generated page via the following URL:

http://blah/products.cfm?search_keyword=bathroom&search_category=451&search_province=Auckland

The dump doesn't display the newly-passed url vars.

I'm obviously missing something pretty basic here.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is replace the opening or closing portion of the tag so that when it gets output you have a valid tag. Something like this:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="page">
 <cfset sCfO = "<" >
 <cfset sCfC = "</" >
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
     <title><cfoutput>#page_title#</cfoutput></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <cfoutput>#sCFO#</cfoutput>cfdump var="#URL#">
     <cfoutput>#sCFO#</cfoutput>cfoutput>
          #URL.myMessage#
      <cfoutput>#sCFC#</cfoutput>cfoutput>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Hopefully that makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your explanations correctly, in your generated with `cfsavecontent` pagevariables are *already* substituted, so you have the static HTML in `products.cfm`. Try to open it in editor and review the code.

I have a question: what is the purpose of using `cfsavecontent` here? What are you trying to achieve? Looks like you may not need it at all, plain ol' CFML should do the job.

Comment: I've oversimplified it to make it easier to explain. Trust me, I need the cfcontent. And sure, the page variables are already substituted. That's the problem I was hoping for an answer for.

Comment: Sorry, such simplified question made me think you have troubles with understanding the CFML basics. Nice to hear that you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would be more inclined to hide that in a function which would read much nicer in your example you could call dumpVariable(url) and encapsulate that in a function. We actually had to do something similar by parsing custom tags from a database into a render function that used cfmodule for the actual implementation. I was pretty happy with the results and it was much easier to tell what was going on in the code than arbitrary character replacement.